# Python CSV: List Index out of Range

Tags: python, csv

I've encountered a problem with a script I've had no luck in solving. I'm pretty new to coding and I've inherited this script. I have read other answers to this problem, but their code looks quite different and some of the solutions didn't work. Here's the code:

```
def CopyFileType(path):
    for file in glob.glob(stage_dir + path):
        csvfile = open(file,'rb')
        csvFileArray = []
        #Line Commented Out - Needed for Python 2
        #for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = '\t'):        
        for row in csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(csvfile, 'utf-8'), delimiter = '\t'):                   
            csvFileArray.append(row)

        string=str(csvFileArray[0])
        c=string.find('Value (en)')
        csvfile.close()
        if c>0:
            shutil.move(file,dest_dir2)
        else:
            shutil.move(file,dest_dir1)
```

And here is there Error Report:

```
D:\Python>C:/Python373/python.exe d:/Python/New_Data_Extract.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Python/New_Data_Extract.py", line 73, in <module>
    CopyFileType(r'\*_SC_*.txt')
  File "d:/Python/New_Data_Extract.py", line 37, in CopyFileType
    string=str(csvFileArray[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I will be honest and say I'm not entirely sure what the script is doing, but I hope maybe someone can spot something obvious and easy to fix? Any insights or thoughts would be super helpful.

I'm wondering if the problem is something to do with the file it is reading, but I'm not sure what to look for.

Comment: Your `reader` doesn't return any results so nothing gets added to that list

Comment: "def CopyFileType(path):
for file in glob.glob(stage_dir + path):" Indentation was lost when pasting, sorry!

Comment: @Sayse could you explain what you mean? Sorry

Comment: If the `csv.reader(...)` returns an empty list (iterable) then the for loop will just move on without appending any rows

Comment: Ah, i think I understand. I don't think the lists are empty, could it be an empty row? How would I go about handling that?

Comment: Its not an empty row, add some print or debugging statements, find out which file is the culprit, open it up and then you need to work out whats odd about its structure that would cause the reader to not find any rows

Comment: Thanks, I will see what that does

Comment: Back, so I've given that a go, and it seems the offending file is not empty, it's full of content

Comment: It has foreign language characters, tab delimited, nothing else seems odd.

Comment: It would help to include a [mcve] of that file, obfuscating data as necessary and perhaps shortened (Just check that whatever you update your question with still causes the same issue)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go in a bit to see if I can isolate it.

Comment: No worries, without a doubt the issue is that your for loop doesn't find anything to iterate over. With the code provided, can't say any more than that really